# passing input file dynamically in mload at run time

Tags: teradata

I have a scenario where we need to pass the input file as  a parameter to MLOAD as my input file gets generated dynamically with a different name each time.
.IMPORT INFILE <&filename>  Here we want the filename to be taken dynamically.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to pass that filename? There's `.accept` to read a parameter from a flat file or an environment variable. Btw, would be easier with TPT

Comment: Generally with this type of scenario we build the mload script dynamically in a separate scripting language that is handling the job for us (powershell, VBA, VBScript, bash, etc.). And then execute mload on the newly generated script.

Comment: I am calling my mload script from SAS. While calling this, I pass the input file name as the parameter and want that to be picked by script to read and load the table. I guess for .ACCEPT to work the variables need to be in a file and the variables in this case would be static but in our case the variable names would change each time.

Comment: `.accept` can read environment variables as well, but I think you'd still need some kind of scripting to set them dynamically.  Can SAS run a shell script first, then the mload script second?